# Cooking on a Himalayan Salt Slab

Tags: equipment, salt

I am interested in purchasing a himalayan pink salt slab to cook on my stovetop.  My cooktop is glass.  The directions for using the salt slab is to be sure to have a space between the heat source and the slab  Can a heat diffuser be used on a glass cooktop and can the slab be used on the heat diffuser?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd ask the vendor if they've tested on that kind of stove or not. The block will last longer if it's heated slowly and evenly; you may be able to develop a process for this on your stove type through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

My mom has a glass top stove...hate it! I use a cooling rack over the burner when I'm trying to not burn a simmering chili. That should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I hate it also but there is no natural gas where I live. Thanks for the info.